# Strange behaviour of CASE modulo returning NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to generate a set of 10,000 records consisting of random occurrences of three values. I'm using `ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 3` to get a random number between 0 and 2 (inclusive). The query works fine if I define the above expression in a `WITH` CTE, then use it in a subsequent `CASE WHEN`. However, when I define it directly in the `CASE WHEN`, I start getting NULLs. What is the reason for this?

```sql
WITH x AS (
    SELECT n 
    FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) v(n)
),
y as (
    SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 3 as r
    FROM x ones, x tens, x hundreds, x thousands
)
SELECT r, 
       CASE r                          WHEN 0 THEN 'Foo' WHEN 1 THEN 'Bar' WHEN 2 THEN 'Baz' END,
       CASE ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 3 WHEN 0 THEN 'Foo' WHEN 1 THEN 'Bar' WHEN 2 THEN 'Baz' END
FROM y
```

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: There's no guarantee on how often that expression will be evaluated (even if it appears to work in the CTE). It being non-deterministic and possibly evaluated multiple times points to why none of the `WHEN` clauses may match.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever how would it ever be a value other than 0,1,2 though?

Comment: @DaleK - it may be `2` when being checked for a match with `0`, then `0` when being checked for a match with `1` or `2`. If you re-roll the dice between evaluating each possible `WHEN`, you're not guaranteed to match any.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that seems worthy of an answer IMHO?

Comment: Per Damien, it is not the case that the expression is evaluated only once, and then all the `WHEN` clauses happen -- instead it is evaluated separately for every `WHEN`, since `CASE x WHEN a THEN ... WHEN b THEN ...` is internally rewritten to `CASE WHEN x = a THEN ... WHEN x = b THEN ...`. This isn't noticeable when using deterministic expressions (which is most of T-SQL) but `NEWID()` is explicitly not deterministic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is (more or less) covered by the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql):

> The simple `CASE` expression operates by comparing the first
> expression to the expression in each `WHEN` clause for equivalency. If
> these expressions are equivalent, the expression in the `THEN` clause
> will be returned.
>
> [..]
>
> - In the order specified, evaluates *input_expression =
>   when_expression* for each `WHEN` clause.
>
> [..]

Note that it does not say *input_expression* is evaluated once, and indeed it is not. Your `CASE` is internally rewritten to

```
CASE 
   WHEN ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 3 = 0 THEN 'Foo'
   WHEN ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 3 = 1 THEN 'Bar'
   WHEN ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 3 = 2 THEN 'Baz'
END
```

And since each evaluation of `NEWID()` produces a new value (one of the few expressions in T-SQL to do so), the results of this expression are entirely nondeterministic and it's possible none of the `WHEN` clauses match while being evaluated in order.

Comment: @JeroienMostert . . . Reading between the lines about what is NOT in the documentation is just a sign of poor documentation (and I think that SQL Server gets this functionality wrong so this should be considered a bug).  But a really good answer!

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Remember, we're now able to submit corrections/improvements to the docs with the "edit" button on top (and this actually works even if it's not fast, I've submitted a few myself), so if you think the docs should be more explicit about this you can probably have them changed. As for whether it's a bug, well, even if it is this definitely sounds like the kind of bug they won't change for fear of breaking existing queries that implicitly depend on it, but it could always be submitted as one.